# Vertical align text on radio input

Tags: html, css

I'm programming two radio buttons for a form. For this buttons, I managed to include text inside and personalize them by using labels. However, when text is included (and although `text-align=center;` is added) it keeps at the top of the button, instead of aligning both vertically and horizontally in the middle of the button. It is aligned horizontally.

[Photo of the present state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZzXD.png)

Here is the code:

```css
.buttonsform #locheck{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius: 40px;
  width: 190.47px;
  height: 45.96px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  
  font-family:Montserrat;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight:500;
  font-size: 18.192px;
  line-height:22px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color:#333333;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.buttonsform #lpcheck{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  width: 190.47px;
  height: 45.96px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  
  font-family:Montserrat;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight:500;
  font-size: 18.192px;
  line-height:22px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color:#333333;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
      <div class="buttonsform">
      <input type="radio" name="odontologia" id="ocheck">
      <input type="radio" name="podologia" id="pcheck">
      <label for="ocheck" id="locheck">Odonotología</label>
      <label for="pcheck" id="lpcheck">Podología</label>
      </div>
```

Comment: You can use `flexbox`;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this styling

```
.buttonsform label {
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Why do I need to use flexbox and "!important"?

Comment: If you remove display: inline-block; in .buttonsform #locheck, it is ok without !important

Answer (score 0):

Try this as I said use `flexbox`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.container .option {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 60px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.container .option:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
.container .option label {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
.container .option input:checked .option {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="option">
        <label for="option_1"> Odonotología </label>
        <input type="radio" id="option_1" />
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <label for="option_2"> Podología </label>
        <input type="radio" id="option_2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if this works!?

Answer (score 0):

**I think you are looking for this.**

```css
    .boxed label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 210px;
border-radius: 50px !important;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px rgb(43, 43, 43);
 
}

.boxed input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
  
}

.boxed input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
 background-color: rgb(17, 173, 235);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>



<form class="boxed">
  <input type="radio" id="cb1" name="skills" value="cb1">
  <label for="cb1">Checkbox 1</label>

  <input type="radio" id="cb2" name="skills" value="cb2">
  <label for="cb2">checkbox2 </label>

 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```